# PHP Mail function fails with exim4

Tags: php, apache, debian, sendmail, exim4

PHP Mail function fails after I upgrade my `Debian` web server to `jessie`. The software versions are,

```
Apache2 : 2.4 
Php : 5.6 
Exim4: 4.8
```

This web server has multiple websites and I use `libapache2-mpm-itk` module to run php by different users for each website. So `www-data` is not used.

I get below error when try to send emails using php mail function.

```
unable to set gid=33 or uid=0 (euid=0): forcing real = effective
```

Sendmail path is,

```
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

and it points to exim,

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -> exim4
```

I found a solution from http://blog.gaiterjones.com/send-php-mail-ubuntu-upgrade/ and issue resolved when I set below setting with `itk` module,

```
LimitUIDRange 0 2000
```

But allowing to `root` user is not recommended for shared server like mine.

Is there a better solution?

**EDIT:**
I found an unresolved bug report of this.
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=797653

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the same MPM? Is SElinux disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this issue. Actual problem is explained here  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=797653.

**Solution 1:**

You can install `ssmtp`. Debian `apt-get` will remove `exim4` when install `ssmtp`. So you will have to configure it to use external smtp server.
Point `php` sendmail path like `sendmail_path   /usr/bin/ssmtp -t -i`. This could differ with different distributions.

**Solution 2:**

You can install `esmtp` and configure it to use localhost smtp. See `/etc/esmtprc`. Point `php` sendmail path like `sendmail_path   /usr/bin/esmtp -t -i`. This could differ with different distributions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message

> unable to set gid=33 or uid=0 (euid=0): forcing real = effective

Using `root` is likely not necessary, group 33 (probably `www-data`) should also suffice.

So you should be able to use `LimitGIDRange 1 9999` instead of `LimitUIDRange`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have tried LimitGIDRange and it didn't work. I'm also looking for an app that can handle emails between apache and exim.